# Update Local Server MySql Database from the Server MySql Database

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysql, web-hosting

How it is possible to update localhost MySql database with  server mysql database at particular interval. Web application is made in PHP and database should be in MySql.

Suppose I have a Database at Hosting site Now i want to update my database at regular interval with Local Host Database at my Local Computer.Please suggest me ??

Comment: What is the OS on your local machine? Do you have SSH access?

Comment: Windows is the OS on my Local Machine

Comment: similar/dupe question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/456900/215170

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to use MySQL's [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) feature. Here's a [walkthrough](http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication) and here's the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html) for reference.

It's worth noting that replication over the internet (rather than a local network) can be slow and you can end up with a slave that's minutes, even hours behind a busy master. Another option could be to periodically [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) the master database and copy it back to your local machine, although if your master is very busy you'll lock databases and hang queries, and if it's very large this process will take a long time.