# Mirror mysql table schema and keeping it in sync

Tags: mysql, sql, synchronization, schema

So I have this problem where I need to create an exact copy of another table (schema, indexes) but not the data. We need to temporarily store data before we move it to the table it mirrors.

I can create a mirror table like `CREATE TABLE foo_mirror LIKE foo;` But I want to automatically update the schema when the schema of the table `foo` changes'.

I have considered temporary tables as well instead of mirror tables but we will have 2 different processes copying data to the mirror table `foo_mirror` and copying data to the actual table `foo`. So I can't use a single session.

So I can compare the schema using the following queries:

```sql
-- for_mirror schema
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `information_schema`.`columns`
WHERE `TABLE_NAME` LIKE 'foo_mirror'

-- foo schema 
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `information_schema`.`columns`
WHERE `TABLE_NAME` LIKE 'foo'
```

I could write some code that will apply updates in a job, or perhaps a trigger. I'm wondering if there is a better way to keep tables in sync or even a tool where I don't need to manage this myself.

I also see a potential problem e.g. Changing the type for a column may fail if data hasn't been updated correctly in the mirror table (string to integer - "one" -> 1).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Synchronize two databases schema in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456900/synchronize-two-databases-schema-in-mysql)

Comment: *I can compare the schema using the following queries* This is partial compare. It does not take some entities into accout (triggers, for example).

Comment: *I want to automatically update the schema when the schema of the table foo changes'.* MySQL have no DDL triggers or notification subsystem. Replication have no according settings/regimes. You may create event procedure (which may have the schedule time short enough, for example, 5 minutes) which checks for schema structure changes and saves (dumps) current schema state if any change occures.